# Website incorrect URL resulting in page not found

Tags: html, url, http-status-code-404

Folks,

We are working on some 404 errors in our website which are due to some malformed URL's. The URL is as below.

http://example.com/in/static/globalShare=yes&currentURL=http://example.com/in/static/content.jsp&title=undefined

I am not sure how the above URL is constructed. Seems the redirection to current URL is not happening properly thereby resulting in 404 error. We checked in code and didn't find anything related to globalshare as well. The current URL is working properly when tested as below

http://example.com/in/static/content.jsp

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is missing the '?' required for the server to understand the query string containing the currentURL.

My guess is that it should be before the globalShare, assuming 
http://example.com/in/static is able to be served.

http://example.com/in/static?globalShare=yes&currentURL=http://example.com/in/static/content.jsp&title=undefined

Whats happening in your case is that the server thinks you are requesting a resource/page which is literally named as globalShare=yes&currentURL=http: which is obviously not the case.
More info on query strings can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: i tried the approach you mentioned above. Even that also didn't work. i am not getting this globalShare parameter in the URL. Haven't heard about this. ideally the above URL should redirect to the current URL which is not happening. Do we have any other approach?